# Compiling Texvc for MediaWiki Math

Tags: php, compilation, mediawiki

I want to install Tex/LaTex on my wiki for mathematical formulas. But I don't know hot to compile Texvc. In installation instructions they say that is the first step. So can anyone help me?

Comment: What OS? The MediaWiki page says all you need to do is type `make` to build the executable.

Comment: I did not try enything, i dont know what to do.

Comment: It is linux os on server, and Win on my PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is already on http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Enable_TeX :-)  Let us know if you have any trouble!